# How to escape this command to add alias in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-alias

I want add alias command to .bashrc. the command like this :

```
xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
```

I am confused to escape character from that command. How to properly modify that command to alias in .bashrc

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make it a function, you won't need to escape *anything*:

```
foo() { xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'; }
```

It looks like this is a standalone command, so there's no need to include `"$@"`.